# Python thread_local data

Tags: python, python-multithreading

Python [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) module documentation [recommends](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data) using `threading.local()`
for storing data that is not to be shared between threads.

Is there any fundamental problem using

```
threading.current_thread().x= 42
```

instead of

```
mydata= threading.local()
mydata.x= 42
```

?

The former pollutes the namespace of the thread object a little, but that can be handled if needed. Other than that, both approaches seem to work, but there must be a reason why the latter is recommended in the docs.